Notification Listener Service: When the app is closed and then reopened, it doesn't record notifications
I'd like to apologies in advance because in this platform i found a lot of articles that concerns the same argument but i didn't found the solution for my case.
As already said inside the title, when the app (with inside Notification Listener Service) works when i open the app and set correct permissions for the first time.
Then, when i relaunch this app after closed, it doesn't work anymore. ( Notifications are stored through firebase.
EDIT: Here the function i expect that gets every notification
    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        // Mark service as running
        if (!isRunning) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Creating persistent notification!");
            isRunning = true;
        }

        // Extract notification details
        Notification newNot = sbn.getNotification();
        String packageName = sbn.getPackageName();
        String title = "";
        String text = "";

        // Extract title and text from notification
        if (newNot.extras != null) {
            title = newNot.extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE);
            CharSequence csText = newNot.extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT);
            text = csText != null ? csText.toString() : "";
        }
        // Extract timestamp
        long timestamp = newNot.when;

        // Upload notification details to Firebase except our notification...
        NotificationData notificationData = new NotificationData(packageName, title, text, timestamp);
        if (!text.equals("Collecting notifications in background...")) {
            databaseReference.push().setValue(notificationData);
        }
    }
}

in the first place i tought it was a problem inherent to FireBase, then i tried to write inside a file in order to understand if at least when i reopen the app the notification would be stored  inside the file, but neither that works.
So in conclusion i think the problem is around the lifetime of the service Notification Listener Service that doesn't initialize well when restarted. Someone knows how to handle this type of situation?
FINAL EDIT: At the very end, the unique way i found is to forcefully restart the service ( executing it even if it is the first time )
(Remember that "Strunz" is the inherited class from Notification Listener Service):
    public void restartNotificationListenerService() {
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, Strunz.class);
        getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }


It is a bit tricky to debug as you don't have direct control over this service lifetime. You are at mercy of system calling onBind() to hook in notification callbacks. Does it restart eventually or is it stuck in destroyed state indefinitely?

Yea i found it stucks and it doesn't close correctly when i close it, above you'll see the edit in which i inserted the method that forcefully close the service.
